# Pasar <html></html> a traves de variable "sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl" en Angular

Tags: html, json, angularjs-2.0, angular4, iframe

---------iframe.component.ts--------

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-iframe',
  templateUrl: './iframe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./iframe.component.css']
})

export class IframeComponent implements OnInit {

  dangerousUrl: string;
  trustedUrl: SafeUrl;
  dangerousVideoUrl: string;
  videoUrl: SafeResourceUrl;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

    this.dangerousUrl = 'javascript:alert("Hi there")';
    this.trustedUrl = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.dangerousUrl);
    this.updateVideoUrl('PUBnlbjZFAI');

  }
updateVideoUrl(id: string) {

    this.dangerousVideoUrl = 'https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/#!?modal_active=none';//Aqui es donde quiero insertar el html para luego pasarlo al iframe

    this.videoUrl =
        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.dangerousVideoUrl);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

---------iframe.component.html------

```
<div class="embed-container">
   <iframe class="e2e-iframe-trusted-src" width="640" height="390" [src]="videoUrl"></iframe>
</div>
```

----------ejemplo.json----------

```
{
    "ejemplo": "8.40",
    "ejemplo1": "3.76",
    "ejemplo2": "0.79",
    "url": "<html><body><h1>HOLA MUNDO</h1></body></html>",
    "ejemplo3": ""
}
```

Comment: Buenas Rai, intenta poner el código escrito sin fotos para que podamos copiarlo y hacer pruebas con él.

Comment: Vale Marc, ya he incluido el codigo

Comment: Prueba con la solución que le dan a este usuario, yo necesitaba bindear una url a la plantilla para ponerla en varios iframes y no había forma de hacerlo con sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382608/angular-6-iframe-binding